# How to create persistent storage on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, persistent-storage

I would like to know which type of persistent storage would be safe to use for Archive files in iPhone? My archive files needs to be updated for every 30mins to 1hr, and i need to persist nearly 500 to 600 archive files.

How to persist so many archive files on device? which persistent storage mehanism woulb be better to use?

Thank You.

Comment: Just wanted to know is it better to use Core Data or SQlite DB?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to choose a DB solution, then I would recommend sticking with what Apple recommends - CoreData.  There is a learning curve, but there are some great docs on the developer portal which should get you up to speed quickly.  CoreData abstracts the DB allowing you to save and retrieve objects rather than write a bunch of SQL.

You might instead wish to look at reading/writing files to the Application home directory.  For more info, please look at the "iOS Application Programming Guide"which has a section on "Files and the File System".  You could then persist your 500 files directly to flash, as opposed to using a DB/CoreData solution.

> Files and the File System
>
> Every application has a protected area
>   in which it can create and modify
>   files. In addition, the system allows
>   applications to share files with each
>   other (and with the user) through
>   well-defined and secure means.
>   However, supporting those means
>   requires work on your part. The
>   following sections describe the types
>   of file-related operations you can
>   perform in your applications.

Link to the programming guide:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults is a quick and easy way to store small amounts of data for you app. We use NSUserDefaults for persistant storage in iphone, like Shared Preference in Android.

**Storing Data:**

```
// create a standardUserDefaults variable
NSUserDefaults * standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// saving an NSString
[standardUserDefaults setObject:@"mystring" forKey:@"string"];

// synchronize the settings
[standardUserDefaults synchronize];
```

**Receiving Data:**

```
// create a standardUserDefaults variable
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// getting an NSString object
NSString *myString = [standardUserDefaults stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
```